# Hamelech Hakadosh

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, chazzan-prayer-leader, aseres-yemei-teshuva

If one is a shaliach tzibur leading the prayers, if in his silent amida he accidentally said ha’kel hakadosh, does he need to begin the amida again or can he rely on his repetition to cover himself?

Additionally, is he able to complete the silent amida knowing that it is unacceptable as he said ha’kel instead of hamelech?

Answer (score 0):

The Kitzur Shuchan Aruch in [סימן יט - דיני משיב הרוח, טל ומטר, יעלה ויבא ועננו](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0018_L2) says:

> **סעיף י"ג**: 
>   שְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר שֶׁטָּעָה בִּתְפִלַּת הַלַּחַשׁ, אֵינוֹ חוֹזֵר וּמִתְפַּלֵּל שֵׁנִית מִפְּנֵי טֹרַח הַצִּבּוּר, אֶלָּא סוֹמֵךְ עַל הַתְּפִלָּה שֶׁיִּתְפַּלֵּל בְּקוֹל רָם, (וְלָכֵן לְאַחַר חֲזָרַת הַתְּפִלָּה יֹאמַר אֱלֹהַי נְצֹר וְכוּ' וְיַפְסִיעַ גּ' פְּסִיעוֹת) אַךְ **אִם טָעָה בּג' בְּרָכוֹת רִאשׁוֹנוֹת** וְנִזְכַּר קוֹדֵם שֶׁהִשְׁלִים תְּפִלָּתוֹ, בְּעִנְיָן שֶׁלֹּא יְהֵא בַּחֲזָרָתוֹ טֹרַח הַצִּבּוּר, יַחְזֹר (קכ"ג קכ"ו). ‏

If he made a mistake in the first 3 Berachot  - like HaKel haKadosh - then he needs to repeat the silent Amida, if he hasn't completed his silent Amida - unless doing so will cause the congregation to wait unnecessarily.

He doesn't say so, but it's inferred he'd finish his Amida, mistake notwithstanding.

The Shulchan Aruch in [סימן קכו - דין שליח צבור שטעה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_6.html#HtmpReportNum0037_L2) is more stringent and insists he always repeats his Amida if a mistake was made in the first 3 Berachot.

However, the Be'er Heitev quoting the Levush says that once he has completed his Amida he can rely on the repetition; though not everybody agrees.

> **ד:** אִם טָעָה שַׁ''ץ כְּשֶׁהִתְפַּלֵּל בְּלַחַשׁ, לְעוֹלָם אֵינוֹ חוֹזֵר וּמִתְפַּלֵּל שֵׁנִית מִפְּנֵי טֹרַח הַצִּבּוּר, אֶלָּא סוֹמֵךְ עַל הַתְּפִלָּה שֶׁיִּתְפַּלֵּל בְּקוֹל רָם, וְהוּא **שֶׁלֹּא טָעָה בְּג'** (ה) **רִאשׁוֹנוֹת**, שֶׁאִם טָעָה בָּהֶם, לְעוֹלָם חוֹזֵר כְּמוֹ שֶׁהַיָּחִיד חוֹזֵר.‏
>
> **באר היטב**  (ה) **ראשונות**. כתב לבוש דוקא כשנזכר קודם שהשלים תפלתו אבל אחר שהשלים תפלתו אינו חוזר ובל''ח חולק ומ''א הסכים כלבוש ע''ש:‏

Comment: How can he finish the Amida if the shemona esrei doesn’t fulfil his obligation - wouldn’t the remainder of the blessings be brachot levatala?

Comment: @Draizy-LeviPine - that's the mystery! the Kitzur seems to imply it's OK - despite your obvious objection.Still  poking around for an explanation.